# Database query optimization, two queries vs one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, optimization

quick question, and I know that they answer may not be a one liner, but..

**Question**

Is it quicker to send one query to table A which has 100 records , say,

**or**

to send two queries to table N which has 50 records...

Thanks !

Comment: Run both cases and check. One query should be faster in almost all cases though.

Comment: It depends on the query execution, while executing two queries will incur an increase of the turnaround time, which I think will be much more than a single query execution

Comment: What's really going to increase query speed is proper indexing, table construction and query construction. Use the explain sql feature often!

Answer (score 0):

Question is not clear..If I understand it correctly, one query would be faster most of the cases, as the table  doesnt have to be read two times

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, this should be put in the comments

Comment: @SashiKant: What do you think an answer for this question.?

Comment: I dont find a question here which needs an answer, so I suggested the OP through comments